# validation in checkbox and select box in jquery

Tags: jquery

My page has multiple rows and each rows one checkbox and one select box, but if any cases checkbox is checked but select box is not select then please show messages.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#myForm").validate({
    rules: {
        myDropDown: {
            required: function(element) {
                if ($("#myCheckbox").is(':checked')) {
                    var e = document.getElementById("myDropDown");
                    return e.options[e.selectedIndex].value == "";
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Provide your code what you've tried so far.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myForm").validate({
    rules: {
               myDropDown:{
                  required: function (element) {
                     if($("#myCheckbox").is(':checked')){
                         var e = document.getElementById("myDropDown");
                         return e.options[e.selectedIndex].value=="" ;                            
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         return false;
                     }  
                  }  
               }
           }
  });
});

Comment: Share your HTML snippet, please.